# Post item with mix of objects and arrays to Mongo - the array does not post data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, vue.js, mongoose

I am posting and item to Mongodb with Node, Express, Mongoose and Vue.js. The item is a mix objects and arrays. The object post succeeds the array post to Mongo and creates an ID but data is not posted.

The Mongoose schema is

```
   const ReportSchema = Schema(
    {
        month: String,
        projects:
        [
          {
          code: String,
          name: String,
          staff: String,
          support: String
          }               // it was missing here 
        ],
```

The API is

```
app.post('/api/report/create', (req, res) => {
  const report = new Report({
    month: req.body.month,
    projects:
    [
      {
      code: req.body.projects.code,
      name: req.body.projects.name,
      staff: req.body.projects.staff,
      support: req.body.projects.support
      }
    ],
```

The Vue.js method is

```
methods: {
    create(){
      let data = { 
        month: this.month,
        projects: [
          {
            code: this.projects.code,
            name: this.projects.name,
            staff: this.projects.staff,
            support: this.projects.supported
          }
        ],
```

When I do a post request in Postman the return is OK for the objects but arrays are not posting data.

```
"report": {
        "_id": "5c91b6d449f21705a0270732",
        "month": "January",
        "projects": [
            {
                "_id": "5c91b6d449f21705a0270733"
            }
        ],
        "__v": 0
    }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I guess there is some mistake in your schema "}" is missing inside projects array

Comment: Did you still facing the same issue or after edit it resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your create method,

```
let data = { 
        month: this.month,
        projects: [
          {
            code: this.projects.code,
            name: this.projects.name,
            staff: this.projects.staff,
            support: this.projects.supported
          }
        ],
```

You are sending projects as an array and accessing it as an object in your API --->
`req.body.projects.code`
Do the following change in your API and it should work.

```
app.post('/api/report/create', (req, res) => {
  const report = new Report({
    month: req.body.month,
    projects: req.body.projects 
})
```